# mongodb querying sub array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have this array with multiple sub-arrays:

```
> db.alumnos111.findOne({curp:'AELJ951211MASCPN04'})
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("520d5440bee9577c283542c3"),
        "nocontrol" : "10301051680201",
        "nombre" : "JANETTE ARACELI",
        "paterno" : "ACERO",
        "materno" : "LOPEZ",
        "curp" : "AELJ951211MASCPN04",
        "generacion" : "2010-2013",
        "carrera" : "INFORMÁTICA",
        "clv_centro" : "01DCT0001F",
        "estado" : "AGUASCALIENTES",
        "plantel" : "CBTIS NO. 168",
        "id_plantel" : "513",
        "materias" : [
                {
                        "semestre" : "4",
                        "nombre_asignatra" : "ECOLOGÍA",
                        "grupo" : "4A",
                        "turno1" : "2001",
                        "parcial1" : "10",
                        "parcial2" : "9",
                        "parcial3" : "9",
                        "calificacion" : "9",
                        "periodo" : "SEMESTRAL 2 - 2011",
                        "id_periodo" : "111",
                        "id_plangpo" : "14",
                        "id_materia" : "4529"
                },
                {
                        "semestre" : "4",
                        "nombre_asignatra" : "FÍSICA I",
                        "grupo" : "4A",
                        "turno1" : "2001",
                        "parcial1" : "8",
                        "parcial2" : "10",
                        "parcial3" : "10",
                        "calificacion" : "9",
                        "periodo" : "SEMESTRAL 2 - 2011",
                        "id_periodo" : "111",
                        "id_plangpo" : "14",
                        "id_materia" : "4530"
                },          
                {
                        "semestre" : "4",
                        "nombre_asignatra" : "INGLÉS IV",
                        "grupo" : "4A",
                        "turno1" : "2001",
                        "parcial1" : "8",
                        "parcial2" : "10",
                        "parcial3" : "9",
                        "calificacion" : "9",
                        "periodo" : "SEMESTRAL 2 - 2011",
                        "id_periodo" : "111",
                        "id_plangpo" : "14",
                        "id_materia" : "4531"
                },        

        ]
}
```

How should I filter the subarray(s) `{"materias.id_materia" : '$in' ("4531",'4530'),'parcial3':10}` of the current `_id`?

Any help in php `db->find` or JavaScript would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should looks something like this

db.alumnos111.find({"materias.id_materia" : { $in : [ "1234", "5678"] }})

to filter out documents w/ id_materia="1234" OR id_materia="5678"

This example would be javascript executed straight in the mongo shell

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

```
db.alumnos111.find( { _id: id }, { materias: { $elemMatch: { id_materia: $in: [ "4531","4530" ], parcial3: 10} }
```

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, the last one did the trick, although the $elemMatch in mongo < 2.2 does not work at all good. I needed to upgrade to 2.4.5 version